# cvblobslib python interface for windows 7

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a way to get the cvblobslib python interface working on windows? I have the opencv interface working after a lot of hassles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use pyblob. It is swig generated python wrapper for cvbloblib. Check below link:

code.google.com/p/pyblobs/

There is another library, cvBlob. It is also similar to cvbloblib.

code.google.com/p/cvblob/

It also has got a python wrapper.

https://github.com/oostendo/cvblob-python

Try whichever best suit you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to cvblob. I have since coded my own Connected component labelling algorithim which is what I intended to use pyblobs and cvblob for.